# How to query by date using mongo repository in spring boot?

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

I have developed an application in spring boot with mongo reposotory. I am using spring data jpa. And I declared in many tables createdDate as Date util package in java and date stores in the db as ISO formatted. When I query using mongo repository **findByCreatedDate(Date date)** which gives no result.

Below is my model class

```
@Document
public class BarModel extends BaseEntity {

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 2, max = 140)
    String name;
    String address;
    String city;
    String state;
    String zipcode;
    String phone;
    String description;
    String primImage;
    @DBRef
    Location location;
    @DBRef
    List<Special> specials;

}

@MappedSuperclass
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public abstract class BaseEntity {

    @Id
    private String id;

    @CreatedBy
    private String createdBy = getCurrentAuditor();

    @CreatedDate
    @DateTimeFormat(iso = ISO.DATE_TIME)
    private Date creationTime = new Date();

    @CreatedBy
    @LastModifiedBy
    private String modifiedBy = getCurrentAuditor();

    @CreatedDate
    @LastModifiedDate
    @DateTimeFormat(iso = ISO.DATE_TIME)
    private Date modificationTime = new Date();
}

@Transactional
public interface BarModelRepository extends MongoRepository<BarModel, String> {

    Page<BarModel> findByCreationTime(Pageable pageable, Date creationtime);

    public List<BarModel> findByCreationTime(Date from, Date to);
}
```

Comment: Can you share your model class

Comment: The above one is my model

Comment: I have given repository as well.

Comment: your method name should be "findByCreationTime" And if you check [this link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongo/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-creation) you can see your methods first parameter should be the query value and the second one is Pagaeable