# How to execute @Query(value="") mongorepository query for fetching execution date records which is in string format

Tags: java, spring-boot, mongorepository

'executedDate' is the field in mongodb in the string format, i need to fetch the record between 2 execute dates, by parsing string format to Date formate using @Query(value="")

I have executed the mongodb query in console as below:

> db.testExecution.aggregate( [ {  $project: {  date: {  $dateFromString: {  dateString: '$executionDate' }  } } }, { $match: { date: { $lt: ISODate("2019-10-16T06:35:03Z") } } } , { $match: { date: { $gt: ISODate("2019-09-16T06:55:03Z") } } } ] )

Output:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d7f8627ea9c671b877d554f"), "date" : ISODate("2019-09-16T06:55:10Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d7f8627ea9c671b877d503f"), "date" : ISODate("2019-10-16T06:25:03Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d7f8627ea9c671b877d502f"), "date" : ISODate("2019-09-16T10:55:55Z") }
```

I need to write this in mongoRepository query format,

when I wrote query like this,

```
@Query(value = "{$project: {date: {$dateFromString: {dateString: '$executionDate'}}}}, {$match: {date: {$lt: ?0)}}} , {$match: {date: {$gt: ?1)}}}")
    List<TestResultResponseDomain> findByExecutionDate(Date from, Date to);
```

I'm getting error as below.

```
Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoQueryException: Query failed with error code 2 and error message 'unknown top level operator: $project' on server localhost:27017
    at com.mongodb.operation.FindOperation$1.call(FindOperation.java:722) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.6.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.operation.FindOperation$1.call(FindOperation.java:711) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.6.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.operation.OperationHelper.withConnectionSource(OperationHelper.java:471) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.6.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.operation.OperationHelper.withConnection(OperationHelper.java:415) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.6.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.operation.FindOperation.execute(FindOperation.java:711) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.6.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.operation.FindOperation.execute(FindOperation.java:83) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.6.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.Mongo$3.execute(Mongo.java:826) ~[mongodb-driver-3.6.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.MongoIterableImpl.execute(MongoIterableImpl.java:130) ~[mongodb-driver-3.6.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.MongoIterableImpl.iterator(MongoIterableImpl.java:77) ~[mongodb-driver-3.6.3.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.executeFindMultiInternal(MongoTemplate.java:2440) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
```

Comment: can you have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45299928/how-to-query-by-date-using-mongo-repository-in-spring-boot

Answer (score 0):

Hi Aggregation cannot be done using `@Query` annotation in Spring-data-mongoDB.
You have to write your custom implementation of respository class and then write aggregation using concrete classes.  You can use below link to get to know how to do it.

https://xpadro.com/2016/04/data-aggregation-with-spring-data-mongodb-and-spring-boot.html